# Excel Macro: why won't this save in the correct directory?

Tags: excel, save

I have an Excel macro that is copying all of the information from a specific worksheet and copying it into a new workbook. The code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TwoSheetsAndYourOut()
Dim NewName As String
Dim nm As Name
Dim ws As Worksheet

If MsgBox("Copy specific sheets to a new workbook" & vbCr & _
"New sheets will be pasted as values, named ranges removed" _
, vbYesNo, "New Copy") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error GoTo ErrCatcher
    Sheets("Input").Copy
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Cells.Copy
        ws.[A1].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        ws.Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Cells(1, 1).Select
        ws.Activate
    Next ws
    Cells(1, 1).Select

    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        nm.Delete
    Next nm

    NewName = InputBox("Please specify the name of your new workbook", "New Copy", "input")

    Dim sPath As String
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs sPath & NewName + ".xls"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
Exit Sub

ErrCatcher:
    MsgBox "Specified sheets do not exist within this workbook"
End Sub
```

However, it does not save the new Excel file in the correct directory. The original Excel file, the one that contains the macro, is in the following directory (on a Mac):

/Applications/WORDNET/PROJECTS

However, every time I run the macro, it saves the new Excel file in the WORDNET folder, instead of the PROJECTS folder.

How do I modify the code so that it saves in the correct place? And why does it not save in the same directory as the original Excel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
```

`sPath` is the path without a seperator at the end (at least on Windows) so you have to add one in your script. In your case, the files will be saved to `/Applications/WORDNET` with the name `"PROJECTS" & NewName`

Unix:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs sPath & "/" & NewName + ".xls"
```

Windows:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs sPath & "\" & NewName + ".xls"
```